# How to set up JOptionPane to have a default button and a different focused button

Tags: java, macos, swing, modal-dialog, defaultbutton

In many native OS X applications, there are dialog boxes that have a default option (in blue) and a different option (in outlined blue) that are initially set. This allows a user to use enter and space, respectively, to choose between two different common options.

[image: 3 option dialog box in OS X with a focused option, and unfocused option, and a default option]

I want to be able to replicate this in a java application. Using JOptionPane in the following way produces something close, but the default option (supplied as the `initialValue` parameter) is both focused *and* the default; The blue outline (and the button activated via the spacebar) should be on the left-most button, but it isn't.

```
int showOptionPane(JFrame parent, String file) {
    String[] selections = {"Save", "Cancel", "Don't Save"};
    return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parent,
            "Do you want to save changes to: " + file + "?",
            "Save Work?",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, selections, selections[0]);
}
```

[image: 3 option dialog box in OS X with two unfocused options, and a default option that is also focused]

I have tried pulling out the source for `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` in an attempt to tweak which button got its focus when displayed to the user, but I was having trouble getting at the buttons themselves (since I think those are specified at the pluggable-look-and-feel). How do I get a button focused that is distinct from the default button?

Comment: You can use the `JRootPane` to specify the "default" button, but it won't be rendered differently then any of the others.  In Java, generally space and enter will activate the currently focused button :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer if you tab to the right in the java application, space and enter do different things on OS X. Enter *always* clicks the default button (filled blue).  (this is specific to this OS)

Comment: Also `JRootPane.setDefaultButton(...)` takes a JButton, but I don't know how to get to the buttons that JOptionPane creates for itself.

Comment: There's a list of issues to start with :P . The reality is, any possible solution will require to implement your own Look and Feel delegate

Comment: I had thought that `JRootPane#setDefaultButton` would allow you to specify the "button" which would be selected when the user presses enter, in some ways it does, but it also changes to what ever button currently has focus :P.  I also dug through the `JOptionPane` `BasicOptionPaneUI`, there is a method called `getButtons` which generates the buttons to be shown on the dialog.  The problem is, in either case, you don't have the means to actually provide additional information which would allow you to specify which would normally be the "default" button

Comment: I would argue that the amount of work that would required to make this work out ways any benefit you might gain and would result in countless hacks which would make it unsuitable to used across platforms

Comment: Also, if you could configure so you could tell it which option "should" be default, you could then try just using `setDefaultCapable` on the `JButton`.  This won't change the key bindings though :P

Comment: Okay, so I started customising `JOptionPane`, I run into issues within `showOptionDialog` method, which I was creating a custom version of to allow the user to specify a `defaultOption` as two of the methods are private <grumble>, okay, we can hack our way around that.  Then I started creating a custom Look and Feel delegate for it, based on `BasicOptionPaneUI` and ran headlong into an impassable issue, one `private` class and one `private` method which would have been perfect to override, as it was configuring the buttons...so the long answer is, no it's not possible, with `JOptionPane`

Comment: OK thanks for your effort. I had the feeling that to get what I wanted, I would have no choice than to drop JOptionPane altogether, start with a JDialog, build from there, and see where that takes me.